# Interesting Python + Regex + scraper issue AttributeError

Tags: python, regex, nonetype

I am trying to find numbers within a list of links that I scrapped earlier.

The problem is that even though regex finds matches, when I try to append them to a different list, I get an error 
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" which I would think means that re.search returned None, but if I check re.search before trying to append, I get all the matches. When I try to create a conditional statement, program just freezes.

Here is the code :

```
category_list = []
for link in links:
    adress = link.contents[3].find_all("a")
    for item in adress:
        if item.has_attr('href'):
            category_list.append(item.attrs['href'])
category_number=[]
for category in category_list:
    number = re.search("\d{2,4}", str(category).decode('utf-8'))
    if number:
        category_list.append(number.group())
```

Comment: What exactly freezes? Does the program enter the `if number` and raise the exception? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Shouldn't that last line be appending to ``category_number``, not ``category_list`` (which you are already iterating over)?

Comment: @jasonharper You are right, thank you, seems I should take a break ;)